# is Sequences, Time Series and Prediction course up to date?

Tags: time-series, prediction, coursera

Recently I asked a question regarding Time series prediction and someone [commented](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637447/low-hanging-fruits-for-a-simple-nn?noredirect=1#comment1191165_637447) that I should consider taking [DeepLearning.AI course: Sequences, Time Series and Prediction](https://www.coursera.org/learn/tensorflow-sequences-time-series-and-prediction?specialization=tensorflow-in-practice).

My goal is to make good Time series predictions.  I wonder whether the fact that it uses TensorFlow instead of the high level layer Keras an issue?   Is there a "best"/most recommended course for developers that want to use Keras to make predictions over Time series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be in good shape if it is leveraging TF 2.X. The Keras API is integrated into the 2.X versions, including sequential model definitions, eager execution, API simplification (Keras), the datasets API, and the SavedModel format.